# Install Very Specific version of Node 4.2.6

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, installation

I would like to install exactly Node4.2.6 version of Node. I am running ubuntu 16.04 and by sudo apt-get install nodejs I get later versions.

I also dont want to follow the following method because this is not recommended and can lead to errors in the future:

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.6/node-v4.2.6.tar.gz -P /tmp/ && \
  tar xvzf /tmp/node-v4.2.6.tar.gz && cd node-v* && \
  ./configure && \
  make && \
  make test && \
  make install
```

I also don't want to install any version and then do

```
nvm install 4.2.6 
nvm use 4.2.6
```

All the above methods are not what I am looking for. Is there another way in ubuntu16.04
Thanks

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has a duplicate question on the Ubuntu Stack Exchange.

Comment: The link does not answer my question. Its a very specific node question. I have googled enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be pretty simple — just need to know which version of Ubuntu you're running (e.g. Trusty or Precise). For example:

```
curl -sO https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x/pool/main/n/nodejs/nodejs_4.2.6-1nodesource1~trusty1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install rlwrap // this is not included with the OS
sudo dpkg -i nodejs_4.2.6-1nodesource1~trusty1_amd64.deb

> Node -v
v4.2.6
```